# Animate subview after animate rootview

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

To summarize and simplify my problem I try to animate a root view and then animate subview.
The first animation work well, but the second most of the time, stay in place.

The layout :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The sample code :

```
TranslateAnimation translateAnimation=new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 300);
    translateAnimation.setDuration(2000);
    translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    translateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            rotateAnimation.setDuration(750);
            rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            rotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);

            imageView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
    });

    container.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

Sometimes I see the imageview tilted. Or rotate, but just one part.
Someone have an idea of what happen ?

I also tried with setFilterAfter(false) and move my container with setTranslationY() on onAnimationEnd but some frames are visible.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

In the real case, the TranslateAnimation is on a ViewPager (to QuickReturn pattern) and the RotateAnimation (to PullToRefresh pattern) inside fragment of ViewPager.
So animations is not necessarily sequential like I have done above, and strongly separated (ViewPager/Fragment).

**EDIT2**

I just see that the touch area don't move with the view.

Comment: What is your min sdk api level?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying it's going to work but let's give this a try:

Let's separate animations and not chain them with animationListener; so instead, let's use the ObjectAnimator and AnimationSet to help us sequence animations for us.

```
ObjectAnimator translateContainer = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(container, "translationY", 300);
translateContainer.setDuration(2000);

ObjectAnimator rotateImage = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "rotation", 0f, 360f);
rotateImage.setDuration(750);

AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
animSet.playSequentially(translateContainer, rotateImage);
animSet.start();
```

Comment: I edited my previous post to describe the reals use case. And in these conditions I can't use AnimatorSet.